# "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found \")\".",

Tags: javascript, arrays, graphql, dom-events

I'm new to graphql and js in general,trying to build as many exercises as I can to learn.  I did the following:

```
var schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query{
        events(): Message
    }

    type Message{
        id: ID!
        random_nr: Int!
    }`);

class Message {

    calculate(){
        var output = [];
        var id = Math.random().toString();
        var random_nr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        output.push(id);
        output.push(random_nr);
        return output;
        console.log(output);
         };
    }

    var root = {  events:()=>{ return new Message(); }}
```

and then in the browser I do:

```
{
  events(){
    calculate()
  }
}
```

receive the title error, can someone shine the light of wisdom into me.

**update**: after adding `()` to events now I receive:

```
{
  "message": "Failed to fetch",
  "stack": "TypeError: Failed to fetch"
}
```

Comment: apparently the previous person ,gave the false answer and probably downvoted me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct answer:

```
var schema = buildSchema(`
    type Message{
        calculate: [Int]
    }

    type Query{
        events: Message
    }   `);
```

and in the browser you **remove all ()** where there are no args!